# Are there any pre-fab CSS Sprites and styles I can apply to my page?

Tags: css, theme, graphics

I'm more of a computer programmer than a designer and I need some sample CSS images that includes images for:

- TabControl
- Close Button for TabControl
- Folder Open/Close
- Buttons
- etc...

Does any premade themes exist that I just start using?  I don't want to start at zero and learn everything at once!

Answer (score 1):

[YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) both have JS controls for most of those things, along with various different stylesheets to apply to them.

You can always extract the DOM structure and build your own system that reuses their CSS.

Comment: +1 for JqueryUI...I use the tab controls extensively in my apps and it's SO simple...plus, can be ajax-ed with nearly 0 configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Have to give some credit to online sprite makers like this: http://csssprites.com/  Between them and free icon sites such as http://www.iconfinder.net you can roll very professional interfaces in no time flat.

As my team's long-time designer once told me, "if you suck at design make something clean and add some snazzy icons...."  Ok, maybe not.

Also, can't forget JqueryUI's buttons as documented here: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/  There's almost no reason to mess around with buttons made from copious layers of "gloss" on Photoshop anymore...these are SO much easier and faster to deliver.

Answer (score 0):

Search XHTML CSS Templates and you'll find tons of templates that come with CSS images for tabs and all those things just a couple of examples: http://www.bluewebtemplates.com/ and http://www.styleshout.com/